# Storing entities for simultaneous edition in one session in EJB JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb-3.0

We have an ideological problem while creating a Web Application in JSF, EJB and JPA.

Our example situation is:

Admin displays the list of users in datatable. Next, he selects user1, which leads him to new user-edition site. The issue occure if he tries to open second card or window and select user2 for simultaneous edition in the same session.
When we try to save user1 data after edition it is not possible, because it is being overwritten in Endpoint by user2.

Data storing:
Because we do not store any data in View part of our project [diagram available below], after displaying it the Managed Beans are being destroyed. Therefore in Controller part we decided to keep the currently selected user as a field in Endpoint [Stateful EJB Bean] which is constant for a session as it is held by Session Scoped Managed Bean. 
We believe we should not store any Collections in Endpoint or Session Scope Managed Bean.

Problem:
Particular case is an overview of the situation. In our application we want to edit multiple entities of the same type during on session.

Question:
Where and how should we store the current selections of User/Admin, which lead to edition of that selected entity.

Storing data in view, request scoped part allowed us to control multiple entities in the same session, though we think it is not appropriate approach. But now storing it in controller part leads to limit of one entity of the same type being edited in the same session.

DIAGRAM HERE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PyYr.jpg

Comment: What app server and what version of it are you using?

Comment: Glassfish 3.1.
What difference does it make @AdrianMitev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a Java EE server (Glassfish 3.1) you could get advantage of using CDI which supports different scopes than JSF. There is a CDI extension called [CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) which provides the so called "window scope", allowing you to scope your beans per browser window which will solve your problem. More info about the window scope can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/EXTCDI/conversations.html).

Another option is to use IceFaces JSF library that also supports its own window scope. More info can be found [here](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Using+Window+Scope).

Comment: I've found similar solution in the meantime but for JBoss, thanks for that link! :)

Answer (score 2):

So the lesson you learned hopefully is to not use the session scope for editing data or for transferring data between pages.

What you should do here is use a GET request with merely the id of the user to be edited. Then on the edit page, use a single *view scoped* backing bean.

Using this pattern you do not need extra extensions. Only if you use CDI beans as backing beans would you need CODI, since the default @ViewScoped unfortunately does not work with CDI beans. CODI provides a version that does work with CDI.

But if you use JSF managed beans, follow the pattern outlined above and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is the GET request really an optimal solution? I've never seen any parameters in any public application while editing data. That's why I guess it is easy, but it's not recommended. @Mike do you use it often?

Comment: It's super efficient and yes, I use it everyday ;)