# PostgreSQL JPA cascade partially working

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, entity

Again we probably have a very simple problem;
our database look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Question (
    idQuestion SERIAL,
    questionContent VARCHAR,

    CONSTRAINT Question_idQuestion_PK PRIMARY KEY (idQuestion),
);

CREATE TABLE Answer (
    idAnswer SERIAL,
    answerContent VARCHAR,
    idQuestion INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT Answer_idAnswer_PK PRIMARY KEY (idAnswer),
    CONSTRAINT Answer_idQuestion_FK FOREIGN KEY (idQuestion) REFERENCES Question(idQuestion),
);
```

So a Question have many Answers.
Following in entity generated by Netbeans 7.1.2 we have field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idquestion", orphanRemoval=true, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<Answer> answerCollection;
```

As you can see I've already added all possible orphan removal and cascade instructions for cascade removal of collection. And it's working fine but for one moment:

You can delete a Question and connected Answers only if they were created in previous 'instance' of our Application. If I first create a new Question and even one Answer and then go straight and delete it we got an error like:

```
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "question" violates foreign key constraint "answer_idquestion_fk" on table "answer"
  Detail: Key (idquestion)=(30) is still referenced from table "answer".
Error Code: 0
Call: DELETE FROM question WHERE ((idquestion = ?) AND (version = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(com.accenture.androidwebapp.entities.Question[ idquestion=30 ])
root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "question" violates foreign key constraint "answer_idquestion_fk" on table "answer"
  Detail: Key (idquestion)=(30) is still referenced from table "answer".
```

If I restart (rebuild, redeploy) the application it's working though.. why? Thanks!

Comment: If you flush() the entity manager then delete, does it succeed then?

Comment: Didn't help. I guess its something with the collection not being reloaded or something. I'm still looking on my own as well :)

Comment: Whatever I do doesn't help... And the problem occurs only in the same 'run'. I can log out from application, close browser, add more questions, no matter what - deleting any question created in the run, cause the error :/

Redeploy and its working...

Comment: Are you using an extended persistence context, or holding an EntityTransaction open a long time? I'm wondering if your application's "runs" are using single giant transactions and keeping everything attached to the EntityManager, rather than using short controlled transactions. It really shouldn't matter if it's a new EntityManager within the same app instance or if it's a new app instance. Long `EntityTransaction`s wouldn't immediately cause your problem, but *will* cause performance issues and risk the loss of uncommitted data and might explain the difference after restart.

Comment: Also, please show your mapping for `Answer`.

Comment: This is Answer mapping:
`@JoinColumn(name = "idquestion", referencedColumnName = "idquestion")
    @ManyToOne
    private Question idquestion;`

in Question entity:
`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idquestion", orphanRemoval=true)
    private Collection<Answer> answerCollection;`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the EclipseLink `@PrivateOwned` extension annotation to your collection mapping.

As for the issue with deletion not working until you restart the app, two things come to mind:

- You might be using very long EntityManager sessions where everything stays attached to the EnitityManager. If that's the case, it's the change of EntityManager session forced by a restart that's helping. Consider using shorter EntityManager sessions by calling `EntityManager.close()` when you're done with a session. Work with detached entities and `EntityManager.merge()` state back in when you want to modify it.
- The second level cache, if any, will be cleared by a redeploy. Try disabling the second level cache and see if that helps.

Comment: What actually helped is `@Overriding` the `remove` method as follows:
`@Override
    public void remove(Question entity) {
        em.refresh(entity);
        super.remove(entity);
    }`

So I guess it is problem with EM session. How can we solve this? Is there something we should look into?

Comment: @Atais Overriding *what* remove method? Some DAO or facade? What does it normally do? As for the session: with the amount of information provided it's nearly impossible to say. You've said nothing about your app's configuration or operation, how sessions are managed, etc.

Comment: Its in facade. Well there would be too much to explain but we've previously made a pricture of our app in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687033/storing-entities-for-simultaneous-edition-in-one-session-in-ejb-jsf

In question there is diagram.

Comment: @Atais OK, you're using stateless session beans (EJB3.1?) for your facades. Are you using a JTA datasource, so the container does transactoin management for you? Or are you using a jdbc datasource with JPA managed transactoins? I'm betting on the latter, and that you're unintentionally getting very long sessions. Consider JTA and container managed tx, it works well when using Stateless EJBs.

Comment: We use jdbc with jpa.... can we do some less harmful changes to the application? we do not really want to change the whole database connection

Comment: @Atais Sure, just think about keeping your individual entity manager sessions short by closing entity managers when your're done with them, not keeping them for the whole app's lifetime, and by keeping your transactions short. Read up on detached entities and on the entity manager session. JTA makes it automatic, but can also be limiting sometimes; you just need a bit more code and bit more thought with direct JDBC data sources.

Comment: We used an automatic code generation for entity facades (Session beans for entities) in Netbeans 7.1.2 and in AbstractFacade which is created there is not a single use of `entityManager.close()` function. So this may cause the problem?

Comment: @Atais Quite possibly. Now you know where to start looking. Enable detailed logging in Eclipselink, look at your session lifetimes and scopes, etc.